# How to remove icons from a toolbar in firefox

Tags: firefox, toolbar

I've just updated my toolbar in Firefox, I accidentally hit restore default button, which brought back the default set.

There are two icons, namely Home and Download, that I don't need - but I can't figure out how to get rid of them.

I've tried dragging them off the side when in 'customize toolbar' mode, but they won't go away, any ideas ?

[image: Firefox toolbar example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the toolbar (not inside the search bar or the address bar) and select "customize" from the menu, then you will be able to drag and drop the desired icons on the toolbar.

Specifically, to remove them from the toolbar, you don't have to "drag them off the side", but drag them inside the new window that will be opened and that contains all available icons.

Comment: sorted, thanks, am i the only one who finds that a little counter intuitive ?

Comment: I don't know, that's the way it works. :)

Comment: Since you can create and have other toolbars apart from the default address bar, I believe that preventing the icon from disappearing when you simply drag it off its current toolbar rather than "put it back" into the modal box is to prevent users from accidentally removing it. Not a huge issue, imo, since customisation is rare and it's easy to get frustrated by accidentally removing something and having to put it back rather than dragging it that extra distance.

Comment: Also: https://people.mozilla.com/~bwinton/australis/customization/mac/
This is the new redesign called "Australis" that is being worked on by Mozilla. Press the menu button and click "customise".